# Convert dataclass containing set of another dataclass to nested dictionary

Tags: python, serialization, immutability, python-dataclasses

I have the following dataclasses:

```py
# model.py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Optional


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Location:
    x: int
    y: int

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.x < other.x and self.y < other.y


@dataclass
class Group:
    locations: set[Location]
    name: str
```

and I want to serialise a Group dataclass to a Python dictionary object. I am attempting to achieve this with the following code:

```py
group = Group(locations={Location(x=0, y=1), Location(x=0, y=0)}, name='foo')
puzzle_dict = dataclasses.asdict(group)
```

however when I do this the returned dict looks like

```py
{'locations': {Location(x=0, y=1), Location(x=0, y=0)}, 'name': 'foo'}
```

whereas I want

```py
{'locations': {{'x': 1, 'y': 0}, {'x': 0, 'y': 0}}, 'name': 'foo'}
```

Calling `dataclasses.asdict` on a single `Location` gives the expected behaviour, but this does not work when calling `dataclasses.asdict` on a `Group`. Any advice?

Comment: dataclasses.asdict(obj, *, dict_factory=dict)
Converts the dataclass obj to a dict (by using the factory function dict_factory). Each dataclass is converted to a dict of its fields, as name: value pairs. dataclasses, dicts, lists, and tuples are recursed into. Other objects are copied with copy.deepcopy().

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying to use a custom dict_factory however I'm not sure how to use it to convert the set of Locations? Do you have any advice?

Comment: If you are doing a project that entails a lot of serializing and deserializing (ie, converting to / from a dict) you might want to take a good look at Pydantic (if you haven't already).  Pydantic models behave similarly to dataclasses but have quite a few additional features that you can make use of.  Among these: it will automatically serialize and deserialize arbitrary levels of nesting, nested collections, etc.

Comment: Thanks @BillHuneke I'll take a look.

Answer (score 1):

Well You are expecting the output to be

```
{'locations': {{'x': 1, 'y': 0}, {'x': 0, 'y': 0}}, 'name': 'foo'}
```

but look at the value of `locations` carefully it's a set of dictionaries which is not allowed in python.

```
>>> {{'x': 1, 'y': 0}, {'x': 0, 'y': 0}}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

If the order is not important you can change the `set` to `list` which will work the `asdict` as expected.

```
>>> from dataclasses import dataclass
>>> import dataclasses
>>> from typing import Optional
>>> 
>>> 
>>> @dataclass(frozen=True)
... class Location:
...     x: int
...     y: int
... 
>>> 
>>> @dataclass
... class Group:
...     locations: list[Location]
...     name: str
... 
>>> group = Group(locations=[Location(x=0, y=1), Location(x=0, y=0)], name='foo')
>>> puzzle_dict = dataclasses.asdict(group)
>>> print(puzzle_dict)
{'locations': [{'x': 0, 'y': 1}, {'x': 0, 'y': 0}], 'name': 'foo'}
```

Comment: Thanks. I think this is useful if the fact that locations is a set isn't too important.

Answer (score 0):

I've actually managed to figure out an answer, thanks in part to the useful comment by @splash58.

```
def factory(data):
    if data[0][0] == "locations":
        locations = list(data[0][1])
        for i, loc in enumerate(list(data[0][1])):
            converted = dataclasses.asdict(loc)
            locations[i] = converted
        data[0] = ("locations", locations)
    return dict(data)
```

but I'll leave up the question in case anyone else has this issue.